# g argument in paintComponent(Graphics g)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am beginner in java. I encounter method `paintComponent()`  in a book and the book says system calls the method when it need to be called.

My question is what is the g argument ?

Is it the object of `Graphics` class or `Graphics2D` class ?

How is it passed by system ?

Is it consist of panel and drawings after we draw components ?

I cant imagine the procedure

Thanks a lot

Comment: `Graphic g` reference can also accept instances of `Graphic2D` class because that class is subtype of `Graphic`. You can find out instance of which class was passed by printing result of `g.getClass()`.

Comment: *"My question is what is the g argument ?"* The Java docs are a wonderful thing, see [`JComponent.paintComponent(Graphics)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-). Having said that, the `Graphics` instance passed to a Swing paint method will *usually* be castable to `Graphics2D`. It's just, that's **not** guaranteed.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson How can a reference to superclass instance be casted to a subclass instance ? i know this is impossible

Comment: What do you mean? If `class Child extends Parent{..}` then with code `void someMethod(Parent p){ Child ch = (Child) p}` is possible and will compile because it is possible to use it with `Child` instance like `someMethod(new Child());`. It may not work if you pass `Parent` instance, but then you will get runtime exception as you should.

Comment: @Pshemo ok thank you. So cast is possible when system passes an argument of type Graphics2D to the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graphics parameter is a Graphics2D object. In this case, the paint method is taking an abstract Graphics class. This class cannot be instantiated. Java will pass it a Graphics2D object, and when you need to use 'g', you need to cast it to Graphics2D to confirm that it is a Graphics2D instance. Then you can use it as a Graphics2D object, and not as an instance that implements the abstract Graphics object.

So while 'g' is a Graphics object, a Graphics2D object is passed for that method, and a cast is required to use it.

This tutorial sums it up nicely (http://www.bogotobogo.com/Java/tutorials/javagraphics3.php):

> The parameter g is a Graphics object. Actually, the object referenced
>   by g is an instance of the Graphics2D class.
>
> So, if we need to use a method from the Graphics2D class, we can' use
>   the g in paintComponent(Graphics g) directly. However, we can cast it
>   with a new Graphics2D variable

I think I found where the actual Graphics2D object is being passed. In the Component.java class, it looks like on line 4356 a SunGraphics2D object is returned and handed down to the JPanel, which invokes the paintComponent.

```
public Graphics getDrawGraphics() {
    revalidate();
     Image backBuffer = getBackBuffer();
      if (backBuffer == null) {
          return getGraphics();
       }
       SunGraphics2D g = (SunGraphics2D)backBuffer.getGraphics();
       g.constrain(-insets.left, -insets.top,
                    backBuffer.getWidth(null) + insets.left,
                    backBuffer.getHeight(null) + insets.top);
       return g;
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly where the Graphics2D object is being made, but its definitely one of the places where its being handed down to the paintComponent method.